# Python sumbodule autloader intellij completion probllem

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I've made following autoloader

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import dirname
from importlib import import_module

def replace(dst: dict, src: dict):
    dst.clear()
    dst.update(src)

replace(globals(), {
    module: getattr(import_module('.' + module, __package__), module)
    for module in [
        file.rstrip('.py')
        for file in listdir(dirname(__file__))
        if not file.startswith('__') and file.endswith('.py')
    ]
})
```

to simplify loading from directory structured like:

```
mod/
    __init__.py (see above)
    foo.py
    goo.py
    ....py
```

so I don't have to write ugly code

```
from mod.foo import foo
```

but instead I can do

```
from mod import foo
```

Unfortunately IntelliJ IDEA community can not handle it and recognize foo as module.

**What can I do to properly parse my module in this IDE?**

Comment: Why is that import ugly?   You do the same exact thing with `os.path`.

Comment: @Makoto not the exact, `os.path` contains more stuff than just `dirname` and `dirname` is not named `path`

Answer (score 1):

In the IDE we don't run your code to collect attributes actually available at runtime, and this code is both way too dynamic to analyze statically and, honestly, quite rare to add some special handling for it. It means that we are not able to tell that these names are even present, let alone properly resolve them.

I'm afraid that the only ways to deal with it are to either suppress all the respective IDE warnings with dedicated comments or to add these names to the whitelist of "Unresolved references" inspection (or retreat to more conventional approach to importing in Python).